# Which is correct way to find error/uncertainty in indirectly measured physical quantity?

Tags: statistics

I have a set of "degree of linear polarization (P)" values for a star. Assume there are 10 P values in the set.

P is defined as square root of sum of squares of fractional Stokes parameters, namely q and u, i.e.

$P = \sqrt{q^2+u^2}$

I have to find error/uncertainty in this set. I am assuming that P values are spread Gaussially.

Physical quantity P is not directly measured. It is a function of 2 directly measured quantities namely q and u.

My query is this: From the following two methods, which is correct method to find error/uncertainty in P ?

```
(a) Just find RMS(standard deviation) of the 10 P values.
This is error in P.
```

OR

```
(b) Using error-propagation technique, find individual error
in each of 10 P values. Then find average of these 10 individual
errors. This average is final error/uncertainty in P.
```

Next, Which is correct way to find average of P:

```
(i) Just find average of 10 P values.
```

OR

```
(ii) First find average of q's and average of u's and then put them in P definition.
```

Comment: For the first question, neither method is correct. You first need to compute variance/error of $P$. Then the variance/error of the average of $10$ P samples will be variance/error divided by $10/\sqrt {10}$. Otherwise, imagine all $10$ values of $P$ are equal. Their STD is zero but clearly some error still propagated. For the second question, you could average $q$ and $u$ only if $P$ linearly depended on them. Since this is not the case here, you need to average $P$'s.

Comment: @A.S. Please elaborate your answer for 1st question; I didn't get it clearly? How do I calculate variance/error of P ?